# Divergence Theorem for a Parabola

Tags: divergence-theorem

Let $E$ be defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the area between the parabola $z = x^2 + y^2$ and the plane $z = 2$. Given the vector $\vec{F} = \langle 2x, 2y, 0 \rangle$, find the flux integral
$\iint_S \vec{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$ using the divergence theorem.

So, we are looking for $$\iiint_E \text{div}\,\vec{F}\,\mathrm{d}V$$
Finding the divergence of $\vec{F}$ is easy, but I've been having trouble with the bounds. How do you set up the bounds for this integral?

Comment: Do you really need to set up a triple integral, there is an easier way to calculate the required volume using a single integral.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what this region looks like? It may help to sketch cross sections.

Comment: @WW1 Yes, it needs to be a triple integral. I thought of this too—why not just think of it as the continuous sum of circles? But they are specifically asking for how to set up the integral.

Comment: @TomKern I do, and it left me more confused than when I started.

Comment: Can you work out what the shadow of the region is in the $xy$ plane? That should give you the $x,y$ bounds (or $r,\theta$ if you want cylindrical coordinates)

Comment: You really should have learned how to evaluate a triple integral of a rather common shape before moving on to the divergence theorem.  Anyway, $\iint_S F dS + \iint_D F \ dD = \iiint_E \nabla\cdot F \ dE,$  where $D$ is a disc in the plane $z = 2.$  That is the real meat of this exercise.  To evaluate $\iiint_E \nabla\cdot F \ dE,$ I would use cylindrical coordinates.  $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt 2}\int_{r^2}^2 r\ dz\ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: That last part was what I was missing! $x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq 2 \implies r^2 \leq z \leq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ V=\int_0^2   \int _{-\sqrt z} ^{\sqrt z} \int_{-\sqrt{z-y^2}}^{\sqrt{z-y^2}}dxdy dz $$

$$ V=2\int_0^2   \int  _{-\sqrt z} ^{\sqrt z} \sqrt{z-y^2} dy dz $$
let $y =\sqrt z \sin \theta$ so that $$.$$ $dy = \sqrt z \cos\theta d \theta$ $$.$$and $\sqrt{z-y^2}  = \sqrt z \cos \theta$

$$ V=2\int_0^2   z\int _ {-\frac \pi 2} ^{\frac \pi 2} \cos ^2 \theta d\theta dz $$
$$ \implies V = \pi \int_0^2 z\; dz = 2 \pi$$

Which is the same answer you get by integrating cross sections parallel to the $x-y$ plane, which are circles having radius $r = \sqrt z$ so each infinitesimal cylinder has volume $dV = \pi z dz$